# Problems with hard drive housed in optical bay of 2011 17" Macbook Pro

Tags: hard-drive, macbook

So I've heard that 2011 MBPs are inconsistently compatible with 6mb/s hard drives in the optical bay, because the chipset was often 3mb/s. I had a 3mb/s drive in there and it worked like a charm. I put in a 6mb/s drive in and it works, but– for example– when I downloaded a movie, the file was somehow corrupted.

Now, I figured the problem was with the optical bay chipset, but it turns out that I have the Intel 6 Series 6mb/s connection.

Some transfers work correctly, but intermittently I've been getting an error message that says: "The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “Some File” can’t be read or written. (Error code -36)"

So what the hell is going on here? Why doesn't my drive work right?

Comment: There's no inherent issue with putting an SATA III drive on an SATA II connection, I have many here with no issues. Check the cables, test the drive.

Comment: Adding to @Tetsujin comment, there could also be the problem with file itself. After checking your disk health, you'd want to check for the presence corrupted files.